# How to Define Custom Number of Items in Comment Feed

Tags: comments, feed, count

Seeking a hook or code to override the Reading-Settings value for Syndication feeds show XXX items specifically for the comment feeds.

Ideally I'd want to roll into a plugin I can network activate on a multiuser site.

I am using Feed Wordpress to syndicate in comment feeds from about 100 student blogs on a multi-user site; I am seeing missed items because the comment feeds only provide 20 at a time (and we have a lot of comment activity). It would be nice to apply a plugin across their blogs to bump that comment feed item count to at least 40, while leaving the other feed settings at the default value.

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter for that! The filter `comment_feed_limit` can be used to adjust the `LIMIT` clause directly. By default, the option from Settings -> Reading is used ("Syndication feeds show the most recent"), but that's used for other feeds as well. The `comment_feed_limit` filter is used exclusively for comment feeds.

```
add_filter( 'comment_feed_limits', 'wpse150187_comment_feed_limits' );

function wpse150187_comment_feed_limits( $limit ) {
    return 'LIMIT 40';
}
```